# Send email with attachments action Mailer Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, email, actionmailer

Following https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/action_mailer_basics.html, I try to configure my app to send email with attachments but I have the error `NameError (undefined local variable or method attachment for #<InvoiceMailer:0x00007fde0d7bfe88>
Did you mean?  attachments)`

Here is what I have in my controller :

```
        array_docs.each do |doc| 
            decoded_doc = URI.decode(doc)               

            tmp_file = Tempfile.new(['bill', '.pdf'])
            tmp_file.binmode
            open(decoded_doc, "Authorization" => bearer_token) do |url_file|
               tmp_file.write(url_file.read)
               tmp_file.rewind
               tmp_file.read
               attachment = tmp_file.path
               InvoiceMailer.send_invoice.deliver
            end
        end
```

Here is my Invoice Mailer :

```
class InvoiceMailer < ApplicationMailer

default :from => 'Test <no-reply@test.co>'

  def send_invoice
    attachments['test-bill'] = File.read(attachment)
    mail(to: "steven@test.com",
    subject: "check if it works")
  end
end
```

And my view send_invoice.html.erb

```
<html>
  <head>
    <meta content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" http-equiv="Content-Type" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Test to check if it works </h1>
    <p>Hello world</p>
  </body>
</html>
```

Added to my development.rb and restart my server :

```
config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :sendmail
config.action_mailer.perform_deliveries = true
config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true
```

How to pass the variable from the controller to the mailer file ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```rb
# controller
InvoiceMailer.send_invoice(attachment).deliver

# mailer
def send_invoice(attachment)
  attachments['test-bill'] = File.read(attachment)
  ...
end
```

Answer (score 0):

this works for me:

in controller

```
attached_file = tmp_file.read

attachment = Array.new
attachment = {filename: "nameoffile.something", file: attached_file}
InvoiceMailer.send_invoice(attachment).deliver
```

the mailer class, you can simplify the attachment via sending only the attached_file, the filename is just be flexible if you want to rename it with other names.

```
def send_invoice(attachment)
   if attachment.present? 
     attachments[attachment[:filename]] = {content: attachment[:file]}
   end
  ...
end
```

Comment: Also works but on my side it's better with : `attached_file = tmp_file.path` and `attachments[attachment[:filename]] = File.read(attachment[:file])`